# Trying to access array offset on value of type null (flashpub)

Tags: php, arrays

My server has been upgrade to PHP 7.4 and I'm looking for a way to fix the issues. The Error is giving from this code:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('session_admin')['logged_in']) {
    // The Error is giving from this code
}

public function index() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('session_admin')['logged_in']) {
        redirect('/admin/dashboard');
    } else {
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation', 'table'));
        $this->load->view('bootstrap/header_login');
        $this->login();
    }
}
```

Comment: If `$this->session->userdata('session_admin')` is empty (no session exists), it will return `null` so when you do `['logged_in']` after it, your code is tryign to use `null` as an array, which will throw that error. You  need to check if `$this->session->userdata('session_admin')` is set and is an array before assuming it is.

Comment: thanks for answer @mangus Eriksson, this code was working before php upgrade

Comment: I can't answer to that, but this isn't a PHP 7.4 specific issue. Good practice is to always verify responses from functions/methods that can return multiple data types. Assumptions are where bugs happens.

Comment: find this : public function load_with_key($key, $value) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, array(
            $key => $value
        ));
        if (sizeof($query->row()) != 0)
            $this->populate($query->row());
        else
            echo FALSE;
    }

Comment: I have no idea what the relevance of that code snippet is to this question.